# Every 3rd Time, Print This

Tags: php

```
<?php

$ohhai = 1;

while ($ohhai != 102)
{
    for($t = 1; $t < $ohhai; $t++)
    {
        //if ($t % 3 == 0)
        //{
            $e = $t / 3;
            if (is_int($e))
            {
                echo "*";

            }
        //}
    }

    echo("<br />");
    $ohhai++;
}

?>
```

What I'm trying to do is output the string every 3rd time, like this:

```
$t = 3;

*

$t = 6;

**

$t = 9;

***
```

and so on. I tried numerous ways to obtain this, and this is the closest I got to it, and this is the closest I get. What this prints out is located here (hard order to type out). How can I go about accomplishing the every 3rd time trick?

Comment: Can you show the exact code that is on http://appstorecrazy.com/phpstoof/pye/test.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/` gives you the quotient. Instead you need take `%` operator and check whether the result of `%` operation is **0** and then print the value.

```
<?php

$ohhai = 1;
$times = 1;   // This is variable that keeps track of how many times * needs to printed. It's fairly straight forward to understand, why this variable is needed.

while ($ohhai != 102)
{
    if ($t % 3 == 0)
    {
        for ( $counter = 0; $counter < $times; $counter++)
        {
            echo "*";
        }
        $times ++;
        echo("<br />");
    }
    $ohhai++;
}

?>
```

Comment: that's the commented out code. with it uncommented, it looks like this: http://appstorecrazy.com/phpstoof/pye/test.php

Comment: @Imnotanerd - Check it. I think that is what you need.

Comment: is $t a mistake? Do you mean $times?

Comment: By the time I noticed, you posted the comment. Corrected. Thanks.

Comment: I moved the $times++; outside the if loop, and placed a /3  after $counter < $times, and now it works! Thanks for your help! :D

Answer (score 2):

```
if($something % 3 == 0)
{
  //do something
}
```

`%` is the modulo operator, it returns the remainder of a division. If the result is 0, the division happened without a remainder.

Comment: that's the commented out code. with it uncommented, it looks like this: http://appstorecrazy.com/phpstoof/pye/test.php

Answer (score 0):

You can use the modulus operator in most languages, i.e. the remainder of a divide operation

if(iterationNumber % 3 == 0) it's the third time.

Comment: that's the commented out code. with it uncommented, it looks like this: http://appstorecrazy.com/phpstoof/pye/test.php

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little unclear on what you're trying to do, but I suspect that what you're missing is the modulus operator, `%`.

In PHP, `x % y` evaluates to the remainder you get when dividing x by y. So if you're counting something and you want to run some code for every third one, you can do:

`if (0 == $count % 3) { 
  // action to perform on every third item
}`

See the PHP Manual at http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php for more information.

Also, I think you might want one more for loop so that you're printing out the right number of *s.

```
<?php

$ohhai = 1;

while ($ohhai != 102)
{

  // we only want to print on multiples of 3
  if( 0 == $ohhai % 3 ) {


   for($t = 1; $t <= $ohhai; $t++){
       echo "*";
   }

   echo("<br />\n");
  }
$ohhai++;
}
```

Comment: that's the commented out code. with it uncommented, it looks like this: http://appstorecrazy.com/phpstoof/pye/test.php

Answer (score 0):

Use the modulo operator.

For example:

1. `10 % 2 = 0` because 2 divides 10 without a remainder.
2. `10 % 3 = 1` because 3 divides 10 with a remainder of 1.

So with your commented code, your script would look like this:

```
<?php

$ohhai = 1;

while ($ohhai != 102)
{
    for($t = 1; $t < $ohhai; $t++)
    {
        if ($t % 3 == 0)
        {
            echo "*";
        }
    }

    echo("<br />");
    $ohhai++;
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$total=102;
for($i=1;$i<=$total;$i++) {
    if($i%3==0){
        for($j=1;$j<=($i/3);$j++)
            echo "*";
        echo "<br/>";
    }
}
```